# AWS China Application Load Balancer ARN not Valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm following this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-listener-certificates.html) to list the certificate of my application load balancer in AWS China Ningxia region.

However, the response of the command always says that the listener ARN I provide to it is not valid.

```
$ aws elbv2 describe-listener-certificates \
  --listener-arn arn:aws-cn:elasticloadbalancing:cn-northwest-1:123456789123:loadbalancer/app/brian-test-load-balancer/d72f15a69743975b

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeListenerCertificates operation: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:cn-northwest-1:123456789123:loadbalancer/app/brian-test-load-balancer/d72f15a69743975b' is not a valid listener ARN
```

I've confirmed that the ARN `arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:cn-northwest-1:123456789123:loadbalancer/app/brian-test-load-balancer/d72f15a69743975b` exists.

[image]

Why do I the error message saying the ARN is not valid?

Is this a bug of AWS China?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right place to get the ARN is the *Listeners* tab

Check the HTTPS listener box and click *Edit*
[image]

Then you'll see the ARN of the listener.
[image]